# Mask R-CNN Background Subtraction Implementation

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, pytorch, image-preprocessing

I am currently attempting to reimplement a paper on fall detection (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9186597). It requires a background subtraction algorithm called Mask R-CNN. Are there any current implementations of this algorithm for background subtraction?

Answer (score 0):

I found this, https://github.com/tony92151/maskrcnn-background-remove

but I didnt use it. I will try using it this week and post more updates here.

Comment: Thanks for the help bud. I'm looking to use one which uses creates a binary video output.

Comment: **Correction** I'm looking to use Mask R-CNN that induces a binary human body contour image